# CSS - show div when select is checked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I'm trying to show div when one of the selects in group is checked and hide when not. I thought this should work, but it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/47ctm349/2/

```css
#form-group-osobko {
  display: none;
}

#odber-1:checked+#form-group-osobko {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="odber">Způsob platby</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-0" value="1"> Dobírka
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-1" value="2"> Hotově při osobním odběru
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-2" value="3"> Platba předem na účet
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" id="form-group-osobko">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="osobniodber">Místo osobního odběru</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="osobniodber" name="osobniodber" type="text" placeholder="14900,11000" class="form-control input-md">
    <span class="help-block">Zadejte PSČ míst možného osobního odběru oddělená čárkou.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should work when you click the checkbox in the middle, the div `id="form-group-osobko"` should appear.

I was trying not to use JS with my bootstrap.

Can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong :(

Thanks.

Comment: The divs are not siblings or children of the inputs so there is no CSS method to do this based on your current strcuture.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution only works, if the div to be displayed is an [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) of the checkbox input, as that is what the `+` selector in CSS means.

If this div is neither a sibling nor a child you can't select it with CSS and will have to use JavaScript.

```css
#form-group-osobko {
  display: none;
}
#odber-1:checked+#form-group-osobko {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="odber">Způsob platby</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-0" value="1">Dobírka
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-1" value="2">Hotově při osobním odběru

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group" id="form-group-osobko">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="osobniodber">Místo osobního odběru</label>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="osobniodber" name="osobniodber" type="text" placeholder="14900,11000" class="form-control input-md">
            <span class="help-block">Zadejte PSČ míst možného osobního odběru oddělená čárkou.</span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-2" value="3">Platba předem na účet
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here would be a simple jQuery solution, using just an additional class to display the div:

```js
$('#odber-1').change(function(){
  $('#form-group-osobko').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
#form-group-osobko {
  display: none;
}
#form-group-osobko.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="odber">Způsob platby</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-0" value="1">Dobírka
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-1" value="2">Hotově při osobním odběru
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="odber-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="odber" id="odber-2" value="3">Platba předem na účet
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group" id="form-group-osobko">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="osobniodber">Místo osobního odběru</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="osobniodber" name="osobniodber" type="text" placeholder="14900,11000" class="form-control input-md">
    <span class="help-block">Zadejte PSČ míst možného osobního odběru oddělená čárkou.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, that actually makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get it https://jsfiddle.net/47ctm349/5/

I just added Javascript, using Jquery. It works for any div anywhere:

```
$('#odber-0').on('change', function(){
if($('#odber-0').is(':checked'))
        $("#form-group-osobko").css("display","block");
else
$("#form-group-osobko").css("display","none");
});

$('#odber-1').on('change', function(){
if($('#odber-1').is(':checked'))
        $("#form-group-osobko").css("display","block");
else
$("#form-group-osobko").css("display","none");
});

$('#odber-2').on('change', function(){
if($('#odber-2').is(':checked'))
        $("#form-group-osobko").css("display","block");
else
$("#form-group-osobko").css("display","none");
});
```

In your case no ideas with CSS.
Good luck!